# Cygwin shortcut for command history

Tags: command-line, cygwin

How can I search the command history in cygwin?

I don't want to keep pressing the arrow keys to execute a command from console command history.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using the default editing mode, do ctrl+R to search back through your history.

If you have done set -o vi to use vi editing mode, then it is esc-/

Comment: Thanks Kevin let me try it out

Comment: This works to me. Ctrl+r and it will prompt the most matched history. Then you can press enter and edit to command to run it.

Answer (score 5):

The `history` command is the way to go. I use

```
h ()
{
    history | cut -f 2- | sort -u | grep -P --color=auto -e "$*"
}
```

so that I can type something like `h git.*MyProgram`, `h ^tar -c`, `h svn:ignore`, etc to pull up a sorted list of past commands matching a regex.

You might also want to add the following lines to ~/.inputrc:

```
# Ctrl+Up/Down for searching command history
"\e[1;5A": history-search-backward
"\e[1;5B": history-search-forward
```

With these in place, you can type a partial command prefix (such as `gi` or `sql`) then use Ctrl+Up to scroll back through the list of just your command history entries that match that prefix (such as `git clone https://code.google.com/p/double-conversion/` and `sqlite3 .svn/wc.db .tables`). This can be a lot faster than searching and then cutting and pasting if you want to edit or re-execute a command that was fairly recent.

Answer (score 3):

I use the `history` command in combination with `grep`, e.g. `history | grep vi` shows all commands where `vi` was used.

Answer (score 3):

Do

```
vi ~/.inputrc
```

Add

For arrow up/down bindings:

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
```

Or for page up/down bindings:

```
"\e[5~": history-search-backward
"\e[6~": history-search-forward
```

Close and open `cygwin`.

Voila.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the "Gnu Bash Manual" (`man bash`) for the command "fc". E.g.`fc -l -80` would list the last 80 commands, while other options let you search with RegEx...

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the easiest way is to pipeline it with less and press search character ("/") and then type the command you wanna find.

```
history | less
```

and then

```
/text to find
```

to find the desired command

Another way

is to append the stdout form history command to a file: `history > /cygdrive/path/file.txt`

and then search  in the document.