# cygwin terminal shortcut up/down key half edited commands not recognized

Tags: bash, command, cygwin, updown

I have a problem accessing partially matched commands in Cygwin using the up/down keys.
Partially entering a command and hitting the up/down keys just loops through the entire history.

Please let me know how to search for previous commands using a partially entered command. Do I have to add anything to `.bashrc`?

Comment: Did you want to use `ctrl+r`, when you used `UP`?

Comment: Improved grammar and question clarity

Comment: @anishsane why don't you make that an answer to the question and link to the relevant bash man page section?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cygwin shortcut for command history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380169/cygwin-shortcut-for-command-history)

Answer (score 0):

To search for matching commands in history, the key-stroke is <kbd>ctrl + r</kbd> : [link to manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html).

<kbd>UP</kbd>/<kbd>DOWN</kbd> keys are used to navigate the history.

However, if you want, you can change the key-bindings using the built-in command: `bind`.

e.g. Below command maps `^Y` to reverse search history. `^Y` is typed as <kbd>ctrl+V</kbd><kbd>ctrl+Y</kbd>

```
bind '"^Y": reverse-search-history'
```